# SDL2: Is it bad to move everything instead of using the view-port?

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I'm working on a top-down RPG game in SDL2. I've gotten to the point where I can move a character around, use sprite-sheets and all that jazz. I started work on the camera using `SDL_RenderSetViewport`. However, I ran into a bunch of issues that I don't really want to deal with. So, instead of moving the viewport when I move the player, I just moved everything else. I have a function that moves all the sprites (excluding the player), which are stored in a `vector`.

I know this results in a lot of math calculations, but would it be inefficient from a rendering perspective? My logic is that since the objects are copied to the `SDL_Renderer` every time that it refreshes. Since they are being recopied, regardless of changes, wouldn't it be the same amount of processing every time?

Comment: Transformations happen anyway, it doesn't really matter which side performs it. It *might* be faster with RenderSetViewport because rendering backend will have to perform viewport remapping anyway, but I expect difference to be negligible - you don't have hundreds of thousands sprites anyway. As a bonus, you're not bound to viewport data type (e.g. float or double) so, if done properly, manual approach can handle huge worlds when floating point wouldn't allow address with adequate precision.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is completely fine.

`SDL_RendererSetViewport` isn't relevant to this issue either way. This function affects the bounds of the final frame, relative to the window. As such, you don't really have any other option.

> Since they are being recopied, regardless of changes, wouldn't it be the same amount of processing every time?

You're right, this doesn't matter. Not to mention, you're (I assume) clearing the screen at the beginning of the frame.

If you're feeling adventurous, you might want to look at using `glTranslatef`, though I don't recommend it, since SDL uses Direct3D on Windows, meaning you'd have to force OpenGL somehow.

I'd say you're safe with your current approach; from looking around the internet, this appears to be a common way to do it.

> I have a function that moves all the sprites (excluding the player), which are stored in a vector.

You're overthinking this a little bit. You can just transform each sprite's position when you're rendering it, which is a lot more efficient than dealing with an entire vector.